# Send Data from android to server (Localhost)

Tags: php, android

I have been trying to send data from android to local server.I get the response on the Logcat on successful sending of data but i cant display it on the webpage.

The Android code is:

```
package rk.android.test.test;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpEntity;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpResponse;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.NameValuePair;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.HttpClient;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.methods.HttpPost;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.util.EntityUtils;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    new DataAsyncTask().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    public class DataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            try {
                String postUrl = "http://192.168.137.1/receiver/receiver.php";
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

// post header
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postUrl);

// add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "Mohan"));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

// execute HTTP post request
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

                if (resEntity != null) {

                    String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
                    Log.v("OP", "Response: " + responseStr);

                    // you can add an if statement here and do oth

                }
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

The php code is :

```
<?php
$reversed = strrev($_POST["action"]);

echo $reversed;
?>
```

Logcat Response is :

```
04-06 02:36:55.789 17879-17959/rk.android.test.test V/OP: Response: nahoM
```

The problem is I get a blank page on loading the receiver.php file!!

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only contents of your file

```
echo strrev($_POST["action"]);
```

Then of course it is going to only print a blank page when navigating to it - because `$_POST['action']` will be unset.

If you want this to display something, change `POST` to `REQUEST` instead, then navigate to it like this:

```
http://server:port/page.php?action=esreveRoTgnirtS
```

Answer (score 0):

The `receiver.php` script responds with the reversed "action" parameter passed in the POST body. Your `HttpClient`-based code provides this parameter value.

When you try loading this URL in a webpage, make sure you pass some parameter value in the POST body. If you don't, `$reversed` will be an empty string and you'll see a blank page.

In order to pass parameters via POST in a web browser, you need to either use XMLHttpRequest, or a `<form>` element, meaning you will need an extra webpage that will have a `<form action=".../receiver.php">` and appropriate `<input name="action">` element.

You could avoid the need for this if instead of `_POST` you used `_GET` or `_REQUEST` (to handle both of these methods). Then you can pass the "action" parameter via the query part of the URL: "..../receiver.php?action=Mohan".